# No me agrega las claves foraneas con Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, netbeans, spring-boot

Hola estoy tratando de crear un mini proyecto con Spring Boot y mysql sobre una inmobiliaria. La base de datos tiene tablas relacionadas entre si.
uno de los problema que tengo es que cuando quiero agregar una nueva propiedad no me agrega las claves foraneas.
Las relaciones en la consola de MyPhpadmin de la base de datos me la muestra bien, si agrego una propiedad manualmente, en las fk me muestra bien las opciones.

Copio la entidad de propiedad la cree con netbeans, creo que el error viene dado por el formato que estoy enviando las claves foraneas. Pero no encuentro info mas concretas de como hacerlo.

````
```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table (name ="propiedad")
public class Propiedad {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@NotNull
private String url;
@NotNull
private String direccion;
@NotNull
private String situacion;
@NotNull
private int dormitorios;
@NotNull
private Boolean pileta;
@NotNull
private Boolean gas_natural;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn (name ="fk_propietario_id")
private Propietario fkpropietarioid;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn (name ="fk_tipo_prop_id")
private Tipo_propiedad fktipo_propid;

public Propiedad() {
}

public Propiedad(String url, String direccion, String situacion, int dormitorios, Boolean pileta, 
Boolean gas_natural, Propietario fkpropietarioid, Tipo_propiedad fktipo_propid) {
    this.url = url;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.situacion = situacion;
    this.dormitorios = dormitorios;
    this.pileta = pileta;
    this.gas_natural = gas_natural;
    this.fkpropietarioid = fkpropietarioid;
    this.fktipo_propid = fktipo_propid;
 }
```
````

Copia la entidades propietario y tipo_prop

````
```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table (name ="propietario")
public class Propietario {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id_propietario;
@NotNull
@Column(name="nombre_propietario", length=50)
private String nombre_propietario;
@NotNull
@Column(name="apellido_propietario", length=50)
private String apellido_propietario;
@NotNull
@Column(name="telefono_propietario", length=50)
private String telefono_propietario;
@NotNull
@Column(name="direccion_propietario", length=50)
private String direccion_propietario;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fkpropietarioid", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Propiedad> propiedades;

public Propietario() {
}

public Propietario(String nombre_propietario, String apellido_propietario, String 
telefono_propietario, String direccion_propietario, List<Propiedad> propiedades) {
    this.nombre_propietario = nombre_propietario;
    this.apellido_propietario = apellido_propietario;
    this.telefono_propietario = telefono_propietario;
    this.direccion_propietario = direccion_propietario;
    this.propiedades = propiedades;
}



public List<Propiedad> getPropiedades() {
    return propiedades;
}

public void setPropiedades(List<Propiedad> propiedades) {
    this.propiedades = propiedades;
}

}
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table (name ="tipo_prop")
public class Tipo_propiedad {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@NotNull
@Column(name="tipo_prop", length=25)
private String tipoPropiedad;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fktipo_propid", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Propiedad> propiedades;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tiposPropiedad", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Cliente> clientes = new HashSet<>();
    
public Tipo_propiedad() {
}

public Tipo_propiedad(String tipoPropiedad, List<Propiedad> propiedades) {
    this.tipoPropiedad = tipoPropiedad;
    this.propiedades = propiedades;
}   
}
````

```
Este es el Json que estoy enviando con Postman. Crea todo en la base de datos menos las Fk que las deja en Null.

    {
    "direccion" : "dsf",
    "dormitorios" : 4,
    "fk_propietario_id": {
    "id": 1 },
    "fk_tipo_prop_id": {
    "id": 2  },
    "gas_natural":false,
    "pileta":false,
    "situacion": "ddsasda",
    "url":"dddddd"
    }

Cual puede ser el error. Aclaro que soy bastante nuevo en esto
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, el problema estaba en el Json. El formato correcto era:
"fkpropietarioid": {
"id_propietario": 1
},
"fktipo_propid": {
"id": 2
},